How large does the isometry in Naimark's theorem need to be for a 3-outcome POVM?
I am interested in the POVM example Nielsen and Chuang give in the discussion about indistinguishability. They define the POVM
$E_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle \langle 1|$,
$E_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(1+\sqrt{2})}  (|0\rangle - |1\rangle)( \langle 0| - \langle 1|)$,
$E_3 = I - E_1 - E_2$
Now based on Naimarks theorem I can represent this POVM in an enlarged Hilbert space, entangling the ancilla space with the physical space and then apply a projective measurement on the ancilla space.
My questions:

How large does the ancilla Hilbert space need to be? I guess in this case it needs to be at least a qutrit to include the 3 possible measurement outcomes, but does it need to be even larger?
How does the entangling $U$ need to look like to implement above POVM in this concrete example?


Note that all POVM elements are rank-1, so you don't need to use the standard ancilla trick, but instead an isometry mapping the 2-dimensional space to a 3-dimensional one. If you do use the ancilla trick then the ancilla must have the same dimension as the number of outcomes. Also note that this is precisely the example shown in the Wikipedia article.

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29989/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8814/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26021/55

Let $\boldsymbol\mu\equiv\{\mu_j\}_{j=1}^m\subset \operatorname{Pos}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ be a POVM whose elements act on a $d$-dimensional space and have unit rank, that is, $\mu_j = w_j \mathbb{P}_{\psi_j}$, $\mathbb{P}_\psi\equiv|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$, for some set of pure states $|\psi_j\rangle$, and non-negative coefficients $w_j$ such that $\sum_j w_j=d$.
Note that we must have $m\ge d$, as otherwise there's not enough elements to obtain a rank-1 POVM.
Then you can implement this POVM as a projective measurement on an $m$-dimensional space, by taking the isometry $V$ such that $V^\dagger |j\rangle=\sqrt{w_j}|\psi_j\rangle$, that is,
$$V = \sum_j \sqrt{w_j} |j\rangle\!\langle \psi_j\rvert.$$
Notice that with this you have by definition $\mu_j = V^\dagger \mathbb{P}_j V = \mathbb{P}(V^\dagger|j\rangle)$. In words, we're saying that the vectors the POVM elements project onto are (modulo scalar factors and a complex conjugate) the rows of $V$.
For example, consider the single-qubit SIC-POVM, whose elements are
$$\mu_1 = \frac12\mathbb{P}_0,
\qquad \mu_2 = \frac12 \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{|0\rangle+\sqrt2|1\rangle}{\sqrt3}\right), \\
\mu_3 = \frac12 \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{|0\rangle+\sqrt2 \omega_3 |1\rangle}{\sqrt3}\right),
\qquad
\mu_4 = \frac12 \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{|0\rangle+\sqrt2 \omega_3^2 |1\rangle}{\sqrt3}\right).
$$
You can implement this via an isometry $V:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^4$, which you can imagine sending the input qubit to two output qubits, and has the form
$$V = \frac1{\sqrt6}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt3&0 \\ 1 & \sqrt2 \\ 1 &\sqrt2 \omega_3 \\ 1 & \sqrt2 \omega_3^2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Notice how this allows to implement the POVM using only two qubits, in contrast with Naimark's theorem, which would give you a three-qubit strategy instead, as Narimark's isometry would in this case have the form
$$V_{\rm Naim} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\0&0 \\ 1 & \sqrt2 \\ \sqrt2 & 2 \\ 1&\sqrt2 \omega_3^2 \\ \sqrt2\omega_3 & 2
\\ 1&\sqrt2 \omega_3 \\ \sqrt2\omega_3^2 & 2.
\end{pmatrix}$$
